# unknown message/error in Java using gradle

Tags: java, gradle

im trying to complete an assignment using gradle in Java and keep running into this message in my unit test.

I am passing all my unit tests fine but since this message displays in red, I thought it might be an error of some sort. Anybody know what this means:

```java
org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator
lambda$logTestDescriptorExclusionReasons$7
INFO: 0 containers and 9 tests were Method or class mismatch
```

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's [junit5](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1774), not gradle. It seems it's default behaviour for java.util.logging.

If you'd like to clear it up, you can add this to build.gradle:

> systemProperty 'java.util.logging.config.file', "${project.buildDir}/resources/test/logging-test.properties"